# Asyncio how to gather a variable amount of corroutines?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm writing a program that at some point needs to gather an unknown amount of corroutines, the program manages multiple accounts and for every account there is a client corroutine, how can I gather the clients for an unknown amount of accounts?

This is my current gather function.

```
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
    main_client.start(token),
    account1.client.start(account.credentials),
    #More accounts should go here
    main_player_control.loop()
    #If possible, also would like to have multiple player controls
))
```

Comment: Why not simply use `asyncio.gather(*coros)` where `coros` is the list of all the coroutines that need to be awaited (e.g. `[start(client) for client in clients]`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Vincent [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48684600/asyncio-how-to-gather-a-variable-amount-of-corroutines/48685276#comment84367091_48684600), you can pass a variable number of coroutines to `asyncio.gather` using the `*` function call syntax. Or, you can call `asyncio.wait`, which accepts a list.

Looking at the code, it is not obvious if a single `gather` is correct either. `gather` starts all the coroutines at once, i.e. runs the authorization coroutines in parallel with the main loop. It could be that some sort of intialization/authorization needs to happen first, followed by the control loop. In that case you might be better served by a `main` coroutine like this:

```
async def main(main_client, token, accounts, main_player):
    # authorize the main client
    await main_client.start(token),
    # authorize all the accounts in parallel
    await asyncio.wait(account.client.start(account.credentials)
                       for account in accounts)
    # once the above is complete, start the main loop
    await main_player_control.loop()

loop.run_until_complete(main(main_client, token, accounts, main_player))
```